# assembly: Input e output, ao compilar e executar, dá logo todo o output e depois o input

Tags: assembly

Olá!
Eu comecei a programar em Assembly! E até agora percebi como dar output, mas agora no input... Não percebo...

Não é de perceber. Vou explicar

Primeiro de tudo: Uso Kali Linux, linker: ld; e Assembler: NASM

Aqui está o código até agora:

```
global _start
section .data
        text1: db "What's your name? "
        text2: db "Hello, "
        text1l: equ $-text1
        text2l: equ $-text2

section .bss
        name resb 16
section .text
_start:
        call _printText1
        call _getName
        call _printText2
        call _printName
        call _exit

_printText1:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, text1
        mov rdx, text1l
        syscall
        ret
_getName:
        mov rax, 0
        mov rdi, 0
        mov rsi, name
        mov rdx, 16
        syscall
        ret
_printText2:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, text2
        mov rdx, text2l
        syscall
        ret
_printName:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, name
        mov rdx, 16
        syscall
        ret
_exit:
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall
        ret
```

O output que esperava seria:

```
What's your name? <INPUT>
Hello, <INPUT>
```

Mas não, o output que foi dado foi assim...

```
What's your name? Hello, <INPUT>
```

Eu sei que deve ser algo muito óbvio ou algo assim, mas por favor alguém pode-me ajudar?

Comment: Isso é devido não ter passado uma nova linha depois de imprimir , `text1: db "What's your name? ", 0x0A` ..  nova linha **(0x0A)**

Comment: @stack.cardoso Continua o mesmo... Só imprime o Hello numa nova linha, ficando `What's your name? <NOVA LINHA> Hello, <INPUT>`

Comment: Quero que o Hello seja imprimido depois do Input e que imprima também o Output